Return only all non-conflicting elements after INSERT ... ON CONFLICT with PostgreSQL?
Let's supposed that I have the following query inserting values in a table with entries being potentially already stored:
      INSERT INTO XXX ( ... ) 
      VALUES ( ... )
      ON CONFLICT (xxx_id) DO UPDATE
      SET ( ... ) = ( ... )

Does PostgreSQL allow a RETURNING statement that would allow me to return ONLY the elements that are not conflicting ?
The point would be to know exactly which entries are purely new and which ones got updated.
I know another way is to proceed with a SELECT statement before with a list of the element I want to check, but I'm concerned about performances going this way if the table grows exponentially, while using this method would allow me to have everything done in one unique query.
Thanks in advance !

Apologies for the instant closure - I'm used to the duplicate flag resulting in just a vote and a comment linking the other thread, but I guess my privileges must've been raised recently. To summarize you can observe the xmax system column that'll behave differently in updated vs inserted rows, or you can return other, regular columns that differentiate update from insert and filter based on that, in a select outside.

@Zegarek I'm don't think it's a clean solution to use system columns, I would prefer a solution based on the upsert itself and the returning clause

There's nothing inherently dirty about using system columns - they are used by pretty much every single query you run and it's beyond your control. The thread also shows an idea how you can achieve that without xmax but that either requires adding a regular column that just does the xmax's job when you need it, and pollutes your schema and wastes space otherwise, or returning the difference in what your insert and update parts do - if there is none, that's not an option.

The recent PostgreSQL 17 release added support for a returning clause in a merge statement - that might also work. It'd be enough to merge..returning merge_action() and that'll give you a list of rows saying update or insert.

@Zegarek For now your trick with xmax does the job as I can return xmax<>0 as a was_updated + the ID I need so I will keep this way.
My point about system columns was that sometimes, it may be restricted to internal usage only and might have adverse side effect when used directly, and also that it was possibly not as human-readable as a proper returning clause ( I work with other junior devs that might not be as used to postgresql as I am ).
Anyways, your solution really helped. Thanks !

While I did figure that out on my own back when I was answering the other thread, I later dug up a bunch of much older threads that had already done the exact same thing, way earlier so I can't claim the trick's mine. I'm not sure what you mean by the internal usage restriction and adverse side effects when used directly. I'd argue it is a proper returning clause :)

As to readbility, the alias clarifies the cryptic xmax<>0, which you can further explain with a comment, but I can't disagree it all sticks out, looking weird. I guess merge..returning merge_action() would be more to your liking if you can afford to update to v17 but it's not unreasonable to expect a function call in that context, even though adequately named, may also cause some level of confusion.
